# Article "the" with the word "display"

Tags: articles

Do I need to put "the" in th following sentence:

> "(The) display of strength is a very good thing in the country."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it or you can omit it.  Both are correct.

Without context, it is preferable to omit it, however using "the" could also be referring to a previous sentence.  For example:

"The politician made a proud speech today.  The display of strength is a very good thing in the country."  In this case, "the display of strength" directly references the act of the politician mentioned in the previous sentence so it is better to add the article.

Comment: Can you explain how it could be omitted?  *Display* is a countable noun, so it needs some kind of determiner.

Comment: Habits of behavior when described in general often omit an article.  *Conversation* is a countable noun, but you could say, "Conversation is a good way to get to know someone."

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you for that explanation.  I honestly didn't know how to explain it myself.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to make a general statement, you could also use **a**:

A display of strength ...

Comment: I think there's a subtle difference between having and omitting the indefinite article.  "A display of strength..." implies that each individual display of strength is individually a good thing.  "Display of strength..." implies that a continuous habit of projecting strength in a visible way is a good thing.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee: The indefinite article as a form of generalization might be better paraphrased as **any**. *A stitch in time saves nine.*  *Any* timely repair spares the need for a far more significant repair.  Or recast as a plural, another form of generalization:  Timely **repairs** spare the need for far more expensive repairs.  I don't think **each** expresses the idea as clearly